# Output type is not defined

Tags: transactions, abap, billing, print-preview, sap-erp

I created a new output type and now I have to assign this new output type to tcode VF02 and then use this new output type as a test for tcode VF03 at Billing document-> Issue Output To. When I enter in tcode VF02 and trying to put this new output created is giving me this error [Output is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzxIr.jpg)

I want to use this new output type as this [Output output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5sdO.jpg) (VF03-> Billing document-> Issue Output To)

How can I fix this?
Thanks,
Arvio

Comment: So what? This doesn't affect nothing. I have something to do and I need response specifically for that thing.

Comment: So you took it off, right? Do you see yourself useful here now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output type must be assigned to an output procedure in transaction 'NACE'. You can use the same procedure of 'RD00' output type.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Finally create a condition record with transaction 'VV31' using you new output type.

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: Hello Nelson, thank you for your kindly response... yes I followed the steps given by you. With "You can use the same procedure of 'RD00' output type" you mean to   use this procedure or to create another one similar to 'RD00'? I created a new procedure similar to 'RD00' then i entered the transaction 'VV31'  than putted there my output type 'ZD14' pressed on Kee combination and a pop-up with radiobuttons appeared i clicked on Sales organization/Billing type and as i know my billing document value, I also know the respective two required but I don't know if I am on the right way. Please help.

Comment: Hi, I meant to say that you should include your output type in the same output procedure of RD00. In fact you should make a copy of RD00 and put your own output type.

Answer (score 0):

[Procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HUtZ.jpg) I created the new procedure similar to 'RD00'.

[Key Combination pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqYrl.jpg) I selected Sales Organization/Billing type.

[Create condition records appeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDFxe.jpg)

Any advice how can I proceed now?

Comment: In general it is used the combination Sales Organization and Customer. It is supposed that you, in this case, enter your Sales Organization code and the Billing Type. This key combination will produce that the output type will be printed when attempting to output an invoice that matches that combination.

Comment: I created a condition for a VBELN that I use to test but i still get that error message on 'VF02' transaction when i try to put the new output type created. I don't know how can I proceed now. Help ;(

Comment: Try to check determination analysis in VF02: `Goto -> Header -> Output` then `Goto -> Determination Analysis` Note that you have to be in change mode (VF02) otherwise you will not be able to analyse.

Comment: Hey boys thanks a lot, I found the right procedure and i putted the changes there, now everything is looking great :D
Especially @NelsonMiranda you are THE BEST, thanks a lot!